# MySQL Count with several criteria coloumn one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data transaction table

```
Table Data (Month,Year,Type,Color)
+-------+------+-----------------------+---------------+
| Month | Year | type                  | Color         |
+-------+------+-----------------------+---------------+
|     1 | 2013 | MATIC                 | BLACK         |
|     1 | 2013 | MATIC                 | BLACK         |
|     2 | 2013 | MATIC                 | BLACK         |
|     2 | 2013 | MATIC                 | RED           |
|     3 | 2013 | MATIC                 | WHITE         |
|     3 | 2013 | MATIC                 | WHITE         |
|     4 | 2013 | MATIC                 | WHITE         |
|     4 | 2013 | MATIC                 | WHITE         |
|     1 | 2013 | SPORT                 | RED           |
|     1 | 2013 | SPORT                 | YELLOW        |
|     2 | 2013 | SPORT                 | YELLOW        |
|     2 | 2013 | SPORT                 | BLACK         |
|     3 | 2013 | SPORT                 | BLACK         |
+-------+------+-----------------------+---------------+
```

i want count number by type,color,year,month 
so the result like this

```
+-------+------+-----------------------+---------------+--------+
| Month | Year | type                  | Color         | Number |
+-------+------+-----------------------+---------------+--------+
|     1 | 2013 | MATIC                 | BLACK         |      2 |
|     2 | 2013 | MATIC                 | BLACK         |      1 |
|     2 | 2013 | MATIC                 | RED           |      1 |
|     3 | 2013 | MATIC                 | WHITE         |      2 |
|     4 | 2013 | MATIC                 | WHITE         |      2 |
|     1 | 2013 | SPORT                 | RED           |      1 |
|     1 | 2013 | SPORT                 | YELLOW        |      1 |
|     2 | 2013 | SPORT                 | YELLOW        |      1 |
|     2 | 2013 | SPORT                 | BLACK         |      1 |
|     3 | 2013 | SPORT                 | BLACK         |      1 |
+-------+------+-----------------------+---------------+--------+
```

its group by month,year,type,color,
What query to get the number ?

Comment: Look up `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`.

Comment: Use GROUP BY and COUNT.  Specify Month, Year, Type and Color for your GROUP BY columns.

Comment: Tq Robert..its Work , :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY month, year, type, color;  --  TA DA!
```

Comment: `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY` is not ANSI standard.

Comment: But it works in MySQL because relational stuff is hard.

Comment: Usually I don't upvote answers to such simple questions, but the "ta da!" is just priceless. On the other hand, this query won't work. @JNK not even in MySQL :) (would work in MySQL with `SELECT table_name.*, count(*) ...`)

Comment: The query will work fine and is 100% by the SQL 2003 standard. As long as the table has only these 4 columns and no more are added ;)

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO This query works perfectly fine....

Comment: @Neal I didn't say it wouldn't work. I said it's not ANSI standard.

Comment: @fancyPants `SELECT count(*), *` would give error. `SELECT *, count(*)` works ok.

Comment: @Neal : It Work, tq..,  Tq So much.. :)

Comment: @onyseven happy to help :-D

Comment: thanks to master, this forum really helped me,